# What is the correct way to make a class globally accessible in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have an api that has been produced from an openapi specification. This produces a series of classes e.g. A class for accessing items in a database.

After login, the user is directed to a home page, on this page and all subsequent pages, I would like for the initialised class (it requires a base url and an auth header), to be accessible through all other pages.

What is the best way to access this class?

Should I be using the the react context API for this or is there a better alternative?

Any links to docs that I should look up would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide an example code or a visual of something you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using axios, create a utiil file which exports axios instance

```
const instance = axios.create({baseURL:"https://api.com"})
axiosInstance.defaults.headers.common = '';
export default axiosInstance;
```